# Is it possible to overload "ref new" to allocate from a specific heap?

Tags: windows-runtime

I'm curious if it's possible to overload the "ref new" operator to allocate memory from a heap of my choosing.  I'm looking to create a library that will allow users to indicate the maximum amount of memory that my library will dynamically allocate.  Internally, I was planning on using HeapCreate and HeapAlloc to define my own heap using the maximum size supplied by the user.  Then, if any of my internal memory allocations exceeed the maximum allotted memory I will fail gracefully.  The problem comes if I have an API that returns a "ref class" (like Platform::String^).  As soon as I use the "ref new" operator then I can't control from what heap the memory is coming and I may break my contract with my user.

Is there any way to overload the "ref new" operator to allocate from my own heap or otherwise keep track of how much memory my library (or DLL) has allocated with "ref new" to ensure that I don't break the contract with my user?

Comment: That's not possible.  It is friendly syntax over COM, it calls a class factory.  Memory is owned by the module that implements the class and managed with reference counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no extension point in the Visual Studio 2012 C++ compiler that will permit you to overload the "ref new" operator.

In addition, your proposed implementation cannot create its own heap using HeapAlloc/HeapFree as this would fail Store certification. Windows Store apps can only access the process heap (GetProcessHeap).